# Remove the "#" in backbone routes

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js

When using the core backbone router, is there a simple way to remove the "#" from the url? right now I have a url that looks like: `somesite.com/#some_back_bone_route/:blog_title` I would like: `somesite.com/some_back_bone_route/:blog_title`. Is this possible?

Every where I have looked doesn't really give a clear answer or direction on how to achieve this or even state if its possible, even the docs are confusing around this subject.

ideas?

Comment: If you remove the # from the links it will make requests to your web server.

Comment: theres no way to remove it but have backbone "Act" like it's there? its preventing me from being able to do things like anchor tags on some pages.

Comment: The `#` is essentially an anchor tag which allows single-page sites to work. Instead of sending data to the server, they transition to another page (similar to moving to the anchor). You have to move to your anchor with another means using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my above comment, with modern browsers (and the history API) it is possible to not use the hash in your URL. Have a look at http://backbonejs.org/#Router (keyword: `pushState`).

But there are some caveats with this method: Your backend may need to be [changed](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

> Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to
>   correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as
>   well. For example, if you have a route of /documents/100, your web
>   server must be able to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL
>   directly.